# Android SqLite: Select Rows Where Values Exists in Another Database Table

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite

I have **two** sqlite databases in my app.  I want to select all rows from a table if a specific column's values exists in another database's table.

This is what I have:

```
// Code to retrieve the string of items
Cursor cr = dbA.rawQuery("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Code, ',') FROM Favourites",
                null);
cr.moveToFirst();     
String Codes = cr.getString(0);   // Returns "A, B, D, S"

// Code to return a table where the rows are in the string
cr = dbB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Favourites WHERE Code IN ('" + Codes + "')",
                null);
return cr;
```

This causes an error because each of the values in the code variable does not have quote marks around it.  The variable is "A, B, D, S" when it should be "'A', 'B', 'D', 'S'".

The question is: do I have to add apostrophes manually around each of the items in the string or is there another way to do it perhaps with the cursor or something, it feels like I am taking a long winded approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL apostrophe `'` is escaped as `''` so you can write:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('''' || Code || '''', ',')
```

where `''''` is an escaped apostrophe in apostrophes and `||` concatenates two strings.

Comment: Even better as I don't need to add the apostrophe in the second part, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
String Codes = "'" + cr.getString(0).replace(", ","','") + "'";
```

Comment: Oh damn that what easy, I think I must have got myself into over complicating that one.  Thanks for your help.